# lighttpd won't reload config, restart, or even stop

Tags: debian, lighttpd

I made some changes to my lighttpd config file and wanted to force-reload but the changes weren’t reflected. I tried stopping and starting it, again with no effect. I then tried simply stopping it. Again, no effect the server is still up and running and serving web pages. I am at a loss....

```
root@webserver:/etc/lighttpd# /etc/init.d/lighttpd force-reload
[ ok ] Reloading lighttpd configuration (via systemctl): lighttpd.service.
root@webserver:/etc/lighttpd# /etc/init.d/lighttpd stop
[ ok ] Stopping lighttpd (via systemctl): lighttpd.service.
root@webserver:/etc/lighttpd# ps aux | grep light
www-data 20600  0.0  0.7  61772  3580 ?        S    Nov03   1:52 /usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
root     25874  0.0  0.3  12656  1624 pts/0    S+   17:04   0:00 grep light
root@webserver:/etc/lighttpd# /etc/init.d/lighttpd start
[ ok ] Starting lighttpd (via systemctl): lighttpd.service.
root@webserver:/etc/lighttpd# /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart
[ ok ] Restarting lighttpd (via systemctl): lighttpd.service.
root@webserver:/etc/lighttpd#
```

Comment: If you back out the change you made does it start/stop normally? You can do a kill -9 on the pid if you really need to get it to stop.

Comment: Restoring the config file had no effect but I was able to kill the process even without -9. I was then able to start and stop it normally. Glad it is working but I am still quite curious about what went wrong.

Comment: My guess is that the config change caused a problem. Try testing with $ lighttpd -t -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (or wherever your new config file is) and see what it says.

Comment: It seems to like it just fine and after being successfully reset the changes work....

Comment: `systemctl status lighttpd` might show helpful data too; also note that lighttpd shouldn't kill active connections, so it may take a while to stop. second signal terminates it though.